# Gluon Mobile information message like Android Toast

Tags: mobile, toast, javafxports, gluon

Is it possible to show a message, in a platform independent way, like what in Android would be a Toast? If not, what would a good way to create similar functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing in Gluon Mobile to the Android Toast control is the [SnackbarPopupView](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/latest/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/SnackbarPopupView.html). The easiest way to do this, is to use the snackbar popup view that is built in into `MobileApplication`:

```
MobileApplication.getInstance().showMessage("Hi There!");
```

We are planning to add Toast functionality as well in a future release.